# Extending expiration of facebook access_tokens not working with PHP webservice

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to follow facebook new guidelines as for extending the access token for 60 days to replace the now deprecated offline_access permission.

I followed the blog post

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/#extend_token
```

I am running this PHP code, which use the graph webservice (not using the facebook API on purpose since I am extending clients tokens from the server for extra security)

```
$ch = curl_init($url);

$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" . $app_id . "&client_secret=" .$app_secret . "&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=" . $_REQUEST['t'];

//return the transfer as a string 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

// $output contains the output string 
$output = curl_exec($ch);


$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

which works, the only problem is it returns with the same access_token (which is fine) and an epoch expiration set to less then 24 hours - meaning the same time it has now, so it does not extend the token.

sample response (access token slightly edited)

```
access_token=BBBCOWPW804EBANG860f0piGXTXMYfY01wXiJgeWHqPdhBcY3g8bCEzYRBiRARARCtX2M2bEi5grt1QalVkTdvaVTrYsYaeyYkOFYDxbncjMDeJf8Vv2V&expires=63918
```

any idea why ? BTW, I did enable the offline_access migration setting in my app settings.

Comment: it doesn't make sense to me that it would even be possible to extend a token this way. I think that the point of tokens expiring in 60 days is to force your user to re-accept it. If Facebook allowed you to renew a token via the server it would entirely defeat the purpose.

Comment: the facebook documents states that after we get a valid access token, it is then the time to send a request without a user intervention using that access token to get an extended one. so I understand your concern but this is exactly as described and it does actually work, doesn't return an error, but doesn't extend the token either...

Comment: "the time to send a request without a user intervention" << What this means is that to renew, user intervention is required. Your solution is not employing the user.

Comment: are you saying it is not possible because you know so ? or do you think it is improper ? because I believe if it was something that requieres user intervention, facebook would not provide a webservice style call... see below..

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: I am saying it is not possible because it makes no sense for it to be possible. Why should the token expire if you can simply renew it server-side? Also, based on what you said about what Facebook said it is not possible. No, I have not tried renewing a token the way you are trying. So, technically I am agnostic as to the availability of such a procedure but I highly doubt it's existence. I don't know what is the purpose of the web-service you are accessing but I doubt that it is for the purpose of renewing an offline_access token for another 60 days... I could be wrong though ;)

Comment: offline_access is not deprecated, facebook offers instead a 60-day token that is achievable "after" the user login and create a standard access token, based on it, we can ask for an extended one, the user already gave us the credentials. I will appreciate if you can read the blog post, it may explain it much better then I can : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/#extend_token

Comment: What type of token are you trying to extend...  A token that's already been extended or a brand new token?

Comment: Moshe, after reading that link I am pretty confused as well. However, this quote from the document makes me think I was at least partially correct: "Note: The user must access your application before you're able to get a valid "authorization code" to be able to make the server-side OAuth call again. Apps will not be able to setup a background/cron job that tries to automatically extend the expiration time, because the "authorization code" is short-lived and will have expired."

Comment: ... what I think that might mean is that you can extend an access_token ONE time server-side. After that you can only extend again after the user accesses your app. Which means, Facebook will allow you to renew an access-token server side but ONLY if the user is accessing your app every once in a while.

Comment: Yes, that was my understanding as well, get the user to authenticate once, get the access token, make one extend request to get a 60 days token. then if the user returns in a week, ask to extend it again and "reset" the timer to 60 days. the only problem is.. the request has no effect right now... @DMCS I am trying to extend a new token that I got with 24-hours lifetime to begin with.

Comment: I'm really not sure what more I can offer, as I don't know how to get the 24hr variety.  I only seem to be able to get 1 hr and 60 day.  So there's something different completely than I'm used to when you get a 24hr token.  I hope someone can assist you.